# Prove $R \times R$ is NOT an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a question, and this is it in entirety:

> Let R be a non-zero ring(that is, R contains at least one element other than the zero element). Prove that $R \times R$ is NOT an integral domain.

Now I haven't done a problem like this before, and it seems to be(from the Wikipedia definition) that this ring $R$ needs to be commutative to be an integral domain. Which it isn't stated to be here. What exactly am I meant to do? I haven't been given anything else than the area in grey.

Comment: Commutativity doesn't matter. Even if it is commutative, it won't be an integral domain, because $(x,0)\times (0,y) = (0,0)$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Oh my, wow, I need to take a break, I have asked two trivial questions in less than thirty minutes... Thank you, that solves it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Elements of $R \times R$ will look like $(x, y)$ such that $x, y \in R$.  Further, multiplication is defined as follows:

$$(a, b)(x, y) = (a \cdot x, b \cdot y)$$

Where $a \cdot x$ and $b \cdot y$ are computed in the original ring $R$.  Addition is defined similarly.

Next, the additive identity (traditionally called "zero") in $R \times R$ will be the element $(0, 0)$.  This is easy to see since $(x, y) + (0, 0) = (x+0, y+0) = (x, y)$.

Finally, to show that $R \times R$ is not an integral domain for *any* ring $R$, it is your task to think of at least two nonzero elements $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ in $R \times R$ such that $(a, b)(c, d) = (0, 0)$.

---

Some clarification:  It is true that all integral domains are commutative.  From this, if $R$ is not commutative, then $R \times R$ is not commutative (why?) and won't be an integral domain.  However, *even if* $R$ is a commutative ring, $R \times R$ is never an integral domain.  This follows from the work above, since the direct product will always have zero divisors.

Comment: How would you extend this to R^3?

Comment: @galois $(r, 0, \dots, 0) (0, r, \dots, r)$ for any $r \neq 0$ (for one)