# Problem on Integral Domain

Tags: ring-theory

Why $n\mathbb{Z} \times n\mathbb{Z}$ is not an integral domain?

Comment: No product of nontrivial rings is a domain.

Comment: FFR http://math.stackexchange.com/q/844337/29335 is probably the most linked duplicate to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $2\mathbb{Z}\times 2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $(-2,0)\times (0,-2)=(0,0)$.